# Constructor Syntax C++

Tags: c++, constructor

```
private:
    int arrSize;
    int currentSize;
    int* arr;
```

```
ArrayClass::ArrayClass(int capacity)
    : arrSize{capacity},
      arr{new int[capacity]}
{
}
```

I came upon this code today, and it is completely new to me.

Is this the same as

```
ArrayClass::ArrayClass(int capacity){
    arrSize = capacity;
    arr = new int[capacity];
}
```

Is there an advantage between one or the other?

Also I did a little research and and saw that:
arrSize{capacity} was just referring to the value of "capacity"
arrSize(capacity) copies the value of "capacity"

Is there any other information I should know about?

Comment: No.  They're not the same.  Google "initializer list" and learn why to use them.

Comment: is it `arrSize{capacity}` or `arrSize(capacity)`. I only know the second construct.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, google list initialization.

Comment: but here they're the same since they're not lists.

Comment: I just googled initialization lists, and I've learned that initialization lists are better than assignment.